# Vue.js: dynamic computed subcomponents

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a situation when I'd like to have a computed local subcomponents. 
My specific case is custom data grid row cell components.
Something like this:

```
var DataGridRow = {
    props: ['columns'],
    template: '<tr><component v-for="col in columns" :is="col.component"></component></tr>',
    components: function () {
        var comps = {};
        // Logic here to build subcomponents dynamically
        return comps;
    }
}
```

In my tests that didn't work.

Does this exist and not documented and I'm doing it wrong?

If not, is it logistically feasible to implement?

Otherwise, is there a better solution, without declaring global components?

EDIT: there's also discussion here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that if `:is` property value is actual component definition and not name, it is not necessary to declare it in subcomponents!

Issue solved!